# How to print continously in QTextEdit in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I try to print variables in QTextEdit in a continuous form and not to print each value in a new line in PyQt5. I use the code below to print values:

```
       for i in myDict.keys():
            L = len(myDict[i])
            if L >= 5:
                self.ui.valueText.append(str(i))
```

the output of this code is like this:

```
1
2
3
...
```

But i want to print them in one line and if i reach the end of Text edit, wrap the text and print them in new line. I want this output:

```
1,2,3,4,5.....
51,52, ....
```

I appreciate any answer on this problem.

Comment: Just create an empty string *before* starting the for loop, append the text to that string, and then call `setText()` *after* the loop is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at first take the text of current QTextEdit and then append it with new value and then print it:

```
        for i in myDict.keys():
            L = len(myDict[i])
            if L >= 5:
                x= self.ui.valueText.toPlainText()
                self.ui.valueText.setText(x+"("+str(i)+","+str(L)+") ,")
```